# In what order do C++ objects passed as arguments to constructors of other objects go out of scope?

Tags: c++, scope

When I compile the following code with g++, the object of class A seems not to be destructed when the object of class C is constructed, and the B.ref_a reference is not broken when accessed by the constructor of object of class C:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A(int aa)
    {
        a = aa;
    }

    ~A()
    {
        std::cout << "A out" << std::endl;
    }

    int a;
};

struct B
{
    B(const A& a)
    : ref_a(a)
    {
    }

    ~B()
    {
        std::cout << "B out" << std::endl;
    }

    const A& ref_a;
};

struct C
{
    C(const B& b)
    {
        c = b.ref_a.a + 1;
    }

    int c;
};

int main(void)
{
    C c(B(A(1)));
    std::cout << c.c << std::endl;
}
```

However, is it guaranteed by the C++ language?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my answer, it seems that I was totally wrong. I hope UncleBens adds an answer because I really got confused :)

Comment: I don't think that's an allowed order of destruction. In your example, `B` should be destructed *before* `A`, not after. The reason is that the constructor of `B` finishes after that of `A`. And destruction order is always the reverse of construction order. What compiler do you use that destructs it afterwards?

Comment: That the constructor of `B` finishes after that of `A` can be seen by looking at the implicit constructor function call of `B(...)`. The temporary `A(1)` is an argument to that function call, and evaluation of function arguments should be complete before the function call is actually done (there is a sequence point before the function is entered). This unambiguously sequences the construction order to `A -> B -> C`, and thus the destruction order has to be `B -> A` (with `C` destructed at the end of `main`).

Comment: But all of those, multiple temporaries are destructed in reverse order, and all of `A` temporaries are destructed in reverse together, after all of `B` temporaries are destructed in reverse together. If you put on optimization, you will usually see only one `A`, and only one `B` object being created though.

Comment: (note that my description assumes that the compiler will potentially create multiple `A` temporaries. This is allowed: Binding a temporary to a const reference may copy the temporary before binding the const reference to the final temporary). C++0x disallowed that copying when binding a const reference to a temporary (rvalue, here), and only one `A`, `B` and `C` object will exist in total.

Comment: I have clarified the question. I was using G++ 4.3.x. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, the temporary objects go out of scope when the instruction has finished its execution. That is, just after the constructor of C has returned.

And yes, this is guaranteed by the C++ standard.

Comment: @quanta_dev Never mind, TheSamFrom1984's answer is a good one too :)